# graphQL - client side query batching - repeat one query for a list of keys

Tags: arrays, graphql, key, concatenation, client

i cannot seem to find much on this, so i dare to ask ....

what is the best practice for "client side query batching" in graphQL?

problem:
i want to repeat one query for a list of keys = a list of "variable objects"
but [the github graphQL server](https://api.github.com/graphql) does not support batch queries
the `/graphql` endpoind returns status 400 bad request,
and the `/graphql/batch` endpoint returns status 404 not found.

naive solution:
concat the sub-queries into a single large query
and rename the variables

stolen from [Batching queries with GraphQL & Python, by Julien Danjou](https://medium.com/mergify/batching-queries-with-graphql-94983b648c3c)

> Modern GraphQL servers accept a JSON array of queries to be sent as
> input.
>
> Unfortunately for us, that’s not the case for GitHub GraphQL API.
>
> The trick here, in ourcase, is to concatenate all the queries and
> name each of them by adding a prefix:
>
> ```
> {
>   Q0: human(id: "1000") {
>     name
>   }
>   Q1: human(id: "1001") {
>     name
>   }
>   # etc...
> }
> ```
>
> In the request above, 9 requests named Q0 to Q9 are being sent. The
> server replies with 9 results, prefixed with the same Q0 to Q9 name.

in javascript that solution looks like

```js
// graphQL query batching in javascript
//
// workaround for servers who reject batch queries
//
// https://medium.com/mergify/batching-queries-with-graphql-94983b648c3c
// https://github.com/Mergifyio/graphql-utils
//
// concept
// 
// concat multiple sub-queries into one large query
// for example to query a list of keys
//
//   keys = [0, 1] = [[a0, b0], [a1, b1]]
//
//   query (
//     $a0: Int, $b0: Int,
//     $a1: Int, $b1: Int,
//   ){
//     # result 0 from key 0
//     r0: object (a: $a0, b: $b0) {
//         field
//     }
//     # result 1 from key 1
//     r1: object (a: $a1, b: $b1) {
//         field
//     }
//   }

// login data for basic authentication
import { username, password } from './login.js'

const url = 'https://api.github.com/graphql'

// add "Repo" sub-query
function qAddRepo(qObj, rIdx, vars){
    /*
        variables:
            repoOwner
            repoName
            commitsCursor
            commitsPerPage
    */
    const sri = '_' + rIdx.toString() // string repo index

    // add variables
    Object.keys(vars).forEach(key => {
        qObj.variables[key+sri] = vars[key]
    })

  // add query
  qObj.query += `
    r${sri}: repository (
      owner: $repoOwner${sri},
      name: $repoName${sri},
    ) {
      nameWithOwner
      # "latest commit" on github
      pushedAt
      # repo create time
      createdAt
      stargazers {
        totalCount
      }
      #isFork
      forkCount
      defaultBranchRef{
        target{
        # master branch
          ... on Commit {
            history(
              after: $commitsCursor${sri},
              first: $commitsPerPage${sri},
            ) {
              # commit count
              totalCount 
              pageInfo {
                # commitsCursor
                endCursor
                hasNextPage
              }
              nodes {
              # commit node
                oid
    }}}}}}
  `
}

// start query object
function qStart(){
    return {
        variables: {},
        query: '',
    }
}

// get graphQL type from javascript type
const qVarType = {
    'cursor': 'String',
    'string': 'String!',
    'number': 'Int!',
    'object': 'String', // cursor?
    // "String" can be null
    // (typeof null) == object
}

// end query object
function qEnd(qObj)
{
    const qVars = Object.keys(qObj.variables).map((key) => {
        // guess cursor data type from variable name
        if (key.substr(key.lastIndexOf('_')-6,6) == 'Cursor') {
            return '$'+key+': '+qVarType['cursor']
        }
        return '$'+key+': '+qVarType[(typeof qObj.variables[key])]
    }).join(',\n')
    
    qObj.query = `query(
        ${qVars}
    ){
        ${qObj.query}
    }`

    // remove whitespace and comments from query
    qObj.query = qObj.query.split('\n').reduce((acc, val) => {
        const val2 = val.trim()
        if (val2[0] == '#' || val2 == '') {
            // remove line
            return acc
        }
        else {
            return acc+'\n'+val2
        }
    }, '')
}



// build query

let qObj = qStart()

qAddRepo(qObj, 0, {
    repoOwner: 'Mergifyio',
    repoName: 'graphql-utils',
    commitsCursor: null, // first page
    commitsPerPage: 2,
})

qAddRepo(qObj, 1, {
    repoOwner: 'octokit',
    repoName: 'graphql.js',
    commitsCursor: null, // first page
    commitsPerPage: 2,
})

qEnd(qObj)

console.log('variables = '+JSON.stringify(qObj.variables, null, '  '))
console.log('query = '+qObj.query)



// send query

const headers = new Headers({
  'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa(username+":"+password),
  'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  'Accept': 'application/json',
})
fetch(url, {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: headers,
  body: JSON.stringify(qObj),
})
.then(r => r.json())
.then(response => {
  // print response
  console.log('response = '+JSON.stringify(response, null, '  '))
})
```

response:

```
{
  "data": {
    "r_0": {
      "nameWithOwner": "Mergifyio/graphql-utils",
      "pushedAt": "2019-07-11T21:43:00Z",
      // ....
    },
    "r_1": {
      "nameWithOwner": "octokit/graphql.js",
      "pushedAt": "2019-12-24T09:45:29Z",
      // ....
    }
  }
}
```

this could be expanded to allow "nested pagination"
with either broad-first-search or deep-first-search strategy

Julien Danjou says:

> As far as we’ve seen, there’s no easy way to build this kind of query
> without doing it yourself. **There is no library doing this.** That’s why
> we had to build our own code.

why not? is it just two people who run into API limitations?
and who cant wait for server admins to change their config?

im still puzzled

related: [GitHub GraphQL API: Resource limitations](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/overview/resource-limitations)